# Is every infinite complete metric space uncountabe?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite complete metric space. My claim is that it is necessarily uncountable. Otherwise there exists a sequence in $X$ which exhausts the space(that is every point of the space is a point of the sequence). Since a singleton in $X$ is nowhere dense, a singleton containing a point of the sequence is nowhere dense. But then $X$ can be expressed as a union of countably many nowhere dense sets which contradicts Baire's category theorem. Is my claim correct?

Comment: The usual rider is that the metric space be "perfect", meaning that it contains no isolated points. Then the singletons are nowhere dense, and the argument follows.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect.  Why must a singleton be nowhere dense?

In fact, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a countably infinite complete metric space, with the usual metric from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think it would be good to point out that every singleton in this space is open, hence somewhere dense.